# automated Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 installation from local DVD with preseed

Tags: preseed

I want to do an automated Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 installation from local DVD, with preseed file fetched from remote **HTTP** server.

Can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late response (I use 16.04 but must be the same) ...

Create a copy of the CD in a local folder:

```
# mkdir /mnt/cdrom
# sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/iso
# mkdir /opt/iso
# cp -rT /mnt/iso /opt/iso
```

Change the timeout to a non zero value in the file /opt/iso/isolinux/isolinux.cfg  (10 == 1 second):

```
path 
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 10
ui gfxboot bootlogo
```

Modify the 'live-install' option in the file /opt/iso/isolinux/txt.cfg to (192.168.1.1 is the location of the web server) and make it default:

```
default live-install
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Xubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
  append auto url=http://192.168.1.1/xubuntu.cfg keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us and console-setup/ask_detect=false boot=casper automatic-ubiquity noprompt initrd=/casper/initrd.lz ---
```

Create the new iso:

```
mkisofs -D -r -V "ATTENDLESS_UBUNTU" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /opt/autoinstall.iso /opt/ubuntuiso
```

Booting with autoinstall.iso the instal·lation will be totally automated.